# CSV file is not uploading in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, csv

I'm unable to upload a CSV file on the WordPress website:

> error: Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons

Check the following image:

[image]

[Website link](http://www.asiatics.com)

Answer (score 1):

I believe, everything is clearly mentioned in the error and you highlighted that too : **This file type is not permitted for security reasons**

To fix this, add this code in wp-config.php

```
define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true);
```

Or you can also use a Plugin called "WP Add Mime Types", And add ONLY types which you want to be added

Comment: another solutions for this issue

Comment: My current hosting is Aws (Amazon Web Server)

Answer (score 0):

Define this in wp-config.php.

```
define(‘ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS’, true)
```

Add this code to your function.php file

```
function enable_extended_upload ( $mime_types =array() ) { $mime_types[‘gz’]  = ‘application/x-gzip’; $mime_types[‘zip’]  = ‘application/zip’; $mime_types[‘rtf’] = ‘application/rtf’; $mime_types[‘ppt’] = ‘application/mspowerpoint’; $mime_types[‘ps’] = ‘application/postscript’; $mime_types[‘flv’] = ‘video/x-flv’; unset( $mime_types[‘exe’] ); unset( $mime_types[‘bin’] ); return $mime_types; } add_filter(‘upload_mimes’, ‘enable_extended_upload’);
```

Comment: Added  both above code  but... the issue still same

Comment: Try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo/ and let me know

Comment: Something else for this problem

Comment: My current hosting is Aws (Amazon Web Server)

Answer (score 0):

In case you are developing a custom theme, add this to your *function.php* file to authorize [MIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) types for uploads:

```
function my_custom_mime_types($mimes) {

    // New allowed MIME type.
    $mimes['csv'] = 'text/csv';

    // Optional. Remove a MIME type.
    unset($mimes['exe']);

    return $mimes;
}
```

> Add it to the filter **upload_mimes**

```
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'my_custom_mime_types');
```

Check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types) for the rest of all MIME types you can authorize.

The point here is that you are controlling all authorized MIME types on your website.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error and found out the problem was the export had been created using a **different WordPress administration language**.

After **renaming the fields to match the target system language**, everything worked like it should.

This means the error message is kind of useless in this case.
I have lost a few days of my remaining life because of this error :(

Answer (score -1):

The simple way out of this issue is simply make an [Excel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel) sheet with the only column you need. Don’t follow the same exported format.

Then convert this Excel document to [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) with online converters and then upload and match the columns. In my case it worked.

Comment: How does that help when the error message is *"error: Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons"*? This seems to answer some other question.