# WooCommerce CSV Importer is not working in WordPress 5.0

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-gutenberg

After updating WordPress 4.9.8 to WordPress 5.0 WooCommerce CSV import seems broken. It will not allow me to upload CSV file to WordPress, can anyone have a solution for this?

Error: **Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons**

Screenshot: http://nimb.ws/uyGKEY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with WordPress version.

Today I posted answered to EXACT same question few hours ago at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844669/csv-file-not-uploading-on-wordpress/53844684#53844684) post

> I believe, everything is clearly mentioned in the error and you
>   highlighted that too : This file type is not permitted for security
>   reasons
>
> To fix this, add this code in wp-config.php

```
 define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true);
```

> Or you can also use a Plugin called "WP Add Mime Types", And add ONLY types which you want to be
>   added

Comment: Yeh! Thanks, @Muhammad It's work for me!

Comment: He wrote question in another way, As he think problem was in his WordPress Versions which i stated too first before answering sir